# i want write a script that when i select table name the related column name of the table is show in the drop down in odoo

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-16

I want to write a script that when I select the table name the related column name of the table is shown in the drop-down.

here is my code...

```
table_name = fields.Selection(
    [('res_partner', 'Contacts'), ('res_company', 'Companies')], string='Table Name',
    tracking=True, required=True)

column_name = fields.Selection([], string='Column Name')

@api.model
def get_column_names(self, table_name):

    query = """
           SELECT column_name
           FROM information_schema.columns
           WHERE table_name = %s
       """
    self.env.cr.execute(query, [table_name])
    result = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    return [(row[0], row[0]) for row in result]


@api.onchange('table_name')
def onchange_table_name(self):
    if self.table_name:
        column_names = self.get_column_names(self.table_name)
        columnlist = [(name[0], name[1]) for name in column_names]
        self.column_name.selection = columnlist
```

I am getting the following error:

```
self.column_name.selection = []
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'selection'
```

how to solve this error..

Answer (score 0):

`self.column_name` should return the field value and because it is a selection field with no selection value its value should be evaluated as `False`.

Odoo will raise the following error if you try to set the selection field value to that list:

```
ValueError: Wrong value for {model_name}.column_name
```

You can use a `Many2one` field instead of a selection field to let users select column names (field names)

***Example:***

```
column_name = fields.Many2one('ir.model.fields')
```

Then use the following domain in XML:

```
domain="[('model', '=', table_name)]"
```

This should filter fields based on the selected table name.

Note that model names are using `.` so you need to replace `_` to match model names. The selection values should be:

```
table_name = fields.Selection([('res.partner', 'Contacts'), ('res.company', 'Companies')],
```